Consume EventHub using Kafka from spark structured streaming job with Service Principal-Secret Auth
I am new working in this and I am building a spark structured streaming job where I am trying to consume EventHub events using Kafka,I followed a official documentation example where uses service principal-secret access to the EventHub. When I am running this code in Synapse Notebook I get an error that Class 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler' not found. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong of I am missing something.
sasl_config = f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId="{client_id}" clientSecret="{client_secret}" scope="https://{event_hubs_server}/.default" ssl.protocol="SSL";'

kafka_options = {
    # Port 9093 is the EventHubs Kafka port
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": f"{event_hubs_server}:9093",
    "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": sasl_config,
    "kafka.sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url": f"https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "subscribe": event_hubs_topic,
    "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "OAUTHBEARER",
    "startingOffsets":"earliest",
    "kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler"
}

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**kafka_options).load()

# Print the contents of the streaming DataFrame to the console
query = df.writeStream \
    .foreach(lambda x: print(x)) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

# Wait for the query to terminate
query.awaitTermination()



According to this documentation you need to be having the callback class extends from org.apache.spark.eventhubs.utils.AadAuthenticationCallback.
So, either you build jar file using the class provided in the above document and add that in synapse.

or
create a jar file out of this project and give class name as mentioned in this stack solution.

I only had to replace the following classes in order to make your code work on Databricks 14.3:
org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule => kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule
org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler => kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
